# Why keeping a list of states "traversed" through doesn't prevent revisiting that state? (Learning Python 5th Edition)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]
[image]

If you've already kept a list of places visited, how can you revisit the state? I'm a bit confused as to what the author meant here.

Comment: Can you add some context to your question? What pattern, algorithm, data structure, etc are you referring to? Is this a state machine, Markov chain, etc? From the few paragraphs you added, it looks like this is a depth-first tree summing algorithm?

Comment: Very hand-wavy answer: the recursive call tree induced by the recursion *implies* a second data structure that helps track which states you have already visited. The non-recursive solution doesn't have this implicit tree; it *only* has the list of states you *plan* to visit, which is *not* a full list of every state you *have* visited.

Comment: @CoryKramer This is under the section Loop Statements Versus Recursion. The author was saying that the non-recursive code written (as a example of how non recursive code can work similarly to recursive code) works for "strictly hierarchical list object trees" and that it doesn't do anything to avoid "cycles". He also mentioned something about data being a "cyclic graph" which frankly I have no idea at all.

Comment: @chepner Hey thanks for your response! Is there a source online that I can read on this? Thanks!